# Replace if/else with something else (e.g. pattern matching)

Tags: python

I compare two sources (a csv file, and the database). I want to get rid of this if/else construct. How can that be achieved with the "python 3.10 pattern matching"

```
for row in csv_file:
    entry = find_entry_in_database(row.get('id'))

    # check for email changes
    if entry[0].email != row.get('email'):
        do_something_with_the_email(email)
    # check for name changes
    if entry[0].name != row.get('name'):
        do_something_with_the_name(name)
    # check for firstname changes
    if entry[0].first_name != row.get('first_name'):
        do_something_with_the_first_name(first_name)
    ...
```

Comment: It's used to replace `if ... elif ... elif ... else`, not several `if`s. https://peps.python.org/pep-0635/#motivation

Comment: @Guy. Thanks for this info....I tried for myself, but can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Guy commented, pattern matching is not for this type of action but rather python implementation of `match` known from other languages. However if you got more fields to deal with the same way you demonstrated, what about creating map that links `entry`'s field with action function, like this:

```py
field_actions = {
    'email': do_something_with_the_email,
    'name': do_something_with_the_name,
    'first_name': do_something_with_the_first_name
}

for row in csv_file:
    entry = find_entry_in_database(row.get('id'))
    for field, action in field_actions.items():
        db_value = getattr(entry[0], field)
        csv_value = row.get(field)
        if db_value != csv_value:
            action(csv_value)
```